# Bootstrap Button Grid-Size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a button that spans 12 columns.

I know how to create a div that is 12 columns as such

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 well"></div>
</div>
```

But that only makes the div 12 columns long. If I was to replace the div with a `input:button` how would I get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `<button></button>`? (bootstrap3)

```
<div class='row'>
<button class='btn btn-lg btn-warning col-lg-12' >button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think the last class `col-lg-12` is doing anything in this case

Answer (score 3):

Add the class `btn-block` and place it inside the 12-column `<div>`. (Note: this is Bootstrap 2.3.2)

```
<div class="row"><div class="span12">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-block btn-primary" type="button">Block level button</button>
</div></div>
```